# How do I Insert using a join in sql expression language?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to do an insert into a table from a select from another couple of tables. Something similar to:

```
INSERT INTO 
`table_b`
SELECT table_a.id, props.description
FROM
    table_a
JOIN 
    props 
    ON props.el_id = table_a.id;
```

How can I do this using SQL Expression Language? I'm talking about SQLAlchemy here.

I know there's a

```
db.execute(insert(table_b).values(id=20, description="another row"))
```

But I cant find a way to use a `select` expression to get the data to be inserted.

Comment: I'm only about 90% sure this is a dup; if that doesn't answer your question, let me know and I'll vote to reopen. (Look at the "Another Edit" part of the accepted answer, assuming you have sqlalchemy 0.8.3 or later.)

Comment: It is indeed a duplicate. Thanks! I'll try and report if the 'another edit' part solution works.